# Is it possible to make an integer only recieve input for one single number instead of two?

Tags: c++, integer

I need to be able to input a series of integers on the same line, I cannot make them characters because I need to add the integers up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int a; //1
int b;     //2
bool sit = true;

cout << "Enter a ten digit date" <<endl;

cin>>a>>b;
cout<<a<<b<<endl;
  if (sit == true){
    b = b+a;
    cout << b<<endl;
  }

    return 0;
}
```

So if I enter

```
12
```

it waits till I enter another two digits then adds both two digit numbers.

```
12
45
57
```

What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: If a character `c` contains a digit (for example, check with the `isdigit()` function), you can get the integer value with `int i = c - '0';`

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to input 12 and get 1+3? is it that?

Comment: Ask for the input, check if it's greater than 10, ask again, then add the two values by digit. To split a 2 digit value into pieces, make use of modolo `%` and integer division `/`, like so: `int x = 12; int x_first = 12 / 10; int x_last = 12 % 10;`

Comment: `cin >> int` reads until it encounters whitespace, a character that does not belong to an integer, etc.  So if you input `12` then it will be read as a single integer `12`, not as separate integers `1` and `2`.  If you need them to be separate, you have to read them as individual characters instead of as integers.

Comment: Are you asking how to read `1` and then `2` as integers if the user enters `12`?

Comment: Re: "I cannot make them characters because I need to add the integers up" -- `char` is an integral type; you can do all the usual arithmetic operations on it, including adding them up. You may well be right that this wouldn't work in practice, because, for example, the value overflows, but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

i dont quite understand your problem , but this is how you read a series of integers .

```
int x;
cin>>x;
//keep reading x until 0 is entered
while(x!=0)
{
//do whatever you need here
cin>>x;
}
```

if you knew how many integers you had to read , you could use a for loop.

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 cin>>number;
}
```